# MySql Can't Start on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I first had the dpkg error having the can't clean mysql package error but i fixed it.
then i reinstalled mysql and started it but it just cant start due to this error :

```
>     ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
>      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-08-25 10:22:15 +08; 1min 55s ago
>     Process: 1250 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
> 
> Aug 25 10:22:15 vps-9be2a25b systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control
> process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Aug 25 10:22:15
> vps-9be2a25b systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result
> 'exit-code'. Aug 25 10:22:15 vps-9be2a25b systemd[1]: Failed to start
> MySQL Community Server. Aug 25 10:22:15 vps-9be2a25b systemd[1]:
> mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5. Aug 25
> 10:22:15 vps-9be2a25b systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server. Aug
> 25 10:22:15 vps-9be2a25b systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request
> repeated too quickly. Aug 25 10:22:15 vps-9be2a25b systemd[1]:
> mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. Aug 25 10:22:15
> vps-9be2a25b systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: Check MySQL's logs.

Comment: There is no MySql Log on my machine

Comment: Then you should re-enable the MySQL log.